# In Gradle version catalog file libs.version.toml plugins name is not recognised

Tags: android, gradle

I am using the version catalog to effectively share the dependency across different Gradle modules in the Android project.

I am using below `libs.versions.toml` file

```
[versions]
room = "2.4.0"
gradlePlugins-agp = "7.0.4"

# Gradle plugins
gradlePlugins-hilt = "2.40.5"

[libraries]
androidx-room-common = { module = "androidx.room:room-common", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }

hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "gradlePlugins-hilt" }
hilt-kapt = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "gradlePlugins-hilt" }
hilt-plugin = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "gradlePlugins-hilt" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "gradlePlugins-agp" }
```

For the above `libs.versions.toml` file while building the app Gradle build fails with the following error

```
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Invalid TOML catalog definition:
  - Problem: In version catalog libs, unknown top level elements [plugins].

* Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Invalid TOML catalog definition:
  - Problem: In version catalog libs, unknown top level elements [plugins].
    
    Reason: TOML file contains an unexpected top-level element.
    
    Possible solution: Make sure the top-level elements of your TOML file is one of 'bundles', 'libraries', 'metadata' or 'versions'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/version_catalog_problems.html#toml_syntax_error for more details about this problem.
```

While the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:plugins) clearly states the plugins are supported top-level name in the toml file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of digging and exploring some open source projects, I found the solution for the above issue. Initially, I was using the `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip` as my Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` but to fix the issue I updated the Gradle version to `7.3.2`

So changing the distribution URL to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.2-all.zip` fixed the issue for me

Comment: still having this problem. I've tried with gradle-7.5.1-all.zip and gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip

Comment: Can you share your `libs.version.toml`? Maybe create a seperate question? It can be related to some other issue

Comment: Somehow it's ok now, can't remember what have i done differently. :/

Comment: Make sure that you are checking `gradlew` version at correct level. Like if you are running the command `./gradlew :app:assemble` at `file_path` then it will pick Gradle wrapper present at that path. But if that module is present inside some other gradle project and then that Gradle wrapper will be picked if same is absent at that path